# ViewPager scrolling on Google Glass

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

How to do smooth scrolling with viewpager on Google Glass?  (in particular viewpagerindicator lib).   I have implemented viewpagers and they work, however swiping on the touchpad quickly scrolls through the views.  I would like to have smooth scrolling similar to the mirror api menus.  Anyone have ideas?  I have attempted to intercept touchevents using the code below, but the overriden methods are not called.  Seems Glass takes the touch events and turns them into d-pad events.  OnPageScrolled(which is useless for what I'm doing) is called, but the other methods are not.

```
class MyViewPager extends ViewPager{
    public MyViewPager(){
    }

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPageScrolled(arg0, arg1, arg2);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(arg0);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.onTouchEvent(arg0);
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can now use the GDK's `CardScrollView` ([javadoc link](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/widget/CardScrollView)) instead of `ViewPager` — it should have all of the functionality that you need.

Comment: Can CardScrollView support any arbitrary view layout?  The documentation recommends to use a Card object, but there are some severe limitations in practice with these cards, for instance with more than a few images being loaded the scrolling becomes jerky and sometimes the app becomes unresponsive.

Comment: Yes, you can have the `CardScrollAdapter` return any kind of views, not just those generated by the `Card` class.

Comment: This works well, much better than Cards actually as the imageviews aren't GC'd and can be loaded asynchronously.  However I can't get the slider scrollbar to show up on the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

I added a GestureDetector to my FragmentActivity, and instead of using the onScroll() event, I used the onFling() event to trigger a page change.

This is the basis for the GestureDetector: http://b2cloud.com.au/how-to-guides/capture-glass-d-pad-events-for-android

And then when a fling was detected, I just updated the page like this:

```
protected void slideForward() {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
}

protected void slideBackward() {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
}
```

Comment: will give this a try.  Although I was hoping to a smooth transition as the user slides forward similar to the Mirror menus.  This is probably the will have to do for now.